# ¿Cómo puedo quitar los márgenes entre dos divs con clase col-lg-6?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando quitar los márgenes que hay entre divs con clase `col-lg-6` para que queden unidos y a su vez añadirles una imagen.

Este es el código que he construido con bootstrap:

```
<!-- Contents -->
<div class="container w-50">
      <div class="row mt-4" id="block-row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center" id="block-col-one">
          <img src="imagen/img1-vid.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center" id="block-col-two">
          <img src="imagen/img3-diapo.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center" id="block-col-three">
            <img src="imagen/img2-abs.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center mb-5" id="block-col-four">
            <img src="imagen/img4-asco.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

El resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedan unos márgenes blancos en medio, ¿cómo podría quitarlos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrías que modificar el `padding` que tienen los `.col-` de Boostrap de manera nativa. Ya que los `.row` tienen un margen negativo que contempla que el primer `col` tenga `padding-left: 15px` y el último `padding-right: 15px` habría que mantener esos **padding** en el primer `col` y en el último.

No hay que olvidar devolver esos `padding` cuando los `col` pasen a ocupar el 100% de la fila, de ahí la **mediaquerie** que puse.

```css
.row .col-lg-6 {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px
}

.row .col-lg-6:first-child {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.row .col-lg-6:last-child {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {

  .row .col-lg-6 {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px
  }
  
  .row .col-lg-6:first-child {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px
  }

  .row .col-lg-6:last-child {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Contents -->
<div class="container w-50">
      <div class="row mt-4" id="block-row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center" id="block-col-one">
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/l1-OIRjsqrc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center" id="block-col-two">
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/l1-OIRjsqrc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center" id="block-col-three">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/l1-OIRjsqrc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center mb-5" id="block-col-four">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/l1-OIRjsqrc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Lo he probado y me ha funcionado bastante bien!